# ffmpeg: How to get list of available codecs with PHP?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, codec

Problem is, I am trying to convert (through php), a .3gp (or any video format) file to ogg.

When I do not specify -vcodec and -acodec, the video is converted, but does not have any audio.

I had read here and other places that I need to specify -acodec libvorbis, however, when I specify the codec as libvorbis, the conversion fails: video converts to 0byte file.

Basically, I am trying to determine if the codec specified is actually part of the ffmpeg build I am using as a process of narrowing down my issue.

Code that produces full length video without sound:

```
$srcFile = 'anyvideo.3gp';
$destFile = 'anyvideo.ogg';
$ffmpegPath = 'path/to/ffmpeg.exe';
$ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($srcFile);
$srcWidth = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameWidth()); 
$srcHeight = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameHeight());
$srcFPS = $ffmpegObj->getFrameRate(); 
$srcAB = intval($ffmpegObj->getAudioBitRate()/1000);
$srcAR = $ffmpegObj->getAudioSampleRate();
$srcLen = $ffmpegObj->getDuration();

exec($ffmpegPath." -i ".$srcFile." -ar ".$srcAR." -s ".$srcWidth."x".$srcHeight." ". $destFile);
```

And the code that produces 0byte file:

```
exec($ffmpegPath." -i ".$srcFile." -acodec libvorbis -ar ".$srcAR." -s ".$srcWidth."x".$srcHeight." ".$destFile);
```

So, my question is, how do I determine the codec's available to ffmpeg using PHP?  Can it even be done?

UPDATED - ANSWER BELOW

Comment: Try ffmpeg by itself first, then try to integrate it into your PHP script once you get a working command. If ffmpeg does not work, then supply the command you tried and the complete console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER:

```
exec($ffmpegPath." -codecs", $codecArr);
for($ii=0,$ii<count($codecArr);$ii++){
    echo $codecArr[$ii];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to see what formats are installed by using the -formats flag on the commandline

```
ffmpeg -formats
```

This will output a long list of codecs available to you.

Comment: I am looking for the php version of what you had suggested, actually the php version of `ffmpeg -codecs` is what I am after, however, I have given you a +1 as those with access to ffmpeg via command line will likely get what they are after with the solution you posted.

Comment: ffmpeg is run from the commandline, even inside of php (looking at exec(ffpeg) in your script above).  What you can do is exec($ffmpegPath . " -formats") and it should give you the same output.

Comment: I apologize for the delay...  I am getting a blank html window when i put `exec($ffmpegPath . " -formats");` any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out `exec($ffmpegPath." -codecs", $codecArr); for($ii=0;$ii<count($codecArr);$ii++){ echo $codecArr[$ii]; }` Will update.

Answer (score 0):

Since ffmpeg version 0.8 it is

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs
```

If you have an older version use

```
$ ffmpeg -formats
```

There are other ffmpeg option syntax changes, too. E.g. -vcodes is -c:v since ffmpeg 0.9.

You might have have also a look to the php library [html5-video-php](https://packagist.org/packages/xemle/html5-video-php) to convert your videos to MP4, WEBM, or OGG formats. The library wraps ffmpeg and considers the different ffmpeg versions. To list all available codecs and retrive basic video infos use:

```
$html5video = new Html5Video\Html5Vide();
$codecsList = $html5video->getEncoders();
$videoInfo = $html5video->getInfo($src);
```